# How get response status

Tags: java, http-headers

All good day!

Example code:

```
        try {
            URL object = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(json);
            wr.flush();
            InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += "\n" + line;
            }
```

How to get the status of a response?
Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con.getResponseCode();` // get status